# Java-Stream & Optional - Find a value that matches to a stream-element or provide a Default value

Tags: java, regex, string, java-stream, option-type

I have a `Dictionary` object which consists of several entries:

```
record Dictionary(String key, String value, String other) {};
```

I would like to replace words in the given `String` my a which are present as a "key" in one of the dictionaries with the corresponding value. I can achieve it like this, but I guess, there must be a better way to do this.

An example:

```
> Input: One <sup>a</sup> Two <sup>b</sup> Three <sup>D</sup> Four
> Output: One [a-value] Two [b-value] Three [D] Four
```

The code to be improved:

```
public class ReplaceStringWithDictionaryEntries {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Dictionary> dictionary = List.of(new Dictionary("a", "a-value", "a-other"),
                new Dictionary("b", "b-value", "b-other"));
        String theText = "One <sup>a</sup> Two <sup>b</sup> Three <sup>D</sup> Four";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<sup>([A-Za-z]+)</sup>").matcher(theText);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int matchLast = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            sb.append(theText, matchLast, matcher.start());
            Optional<Dictionary> dict = dictionary.stream().filter(f -> f.key().equals(matcher.group(1))).findFirst();
            if (dict.isPresent()) {
                sb.append("[").append(dict.get().value()).append("]");
            } else {
                sb.append("[").append(matcher.group(1)).append("]");
            }

            matchLast = matcher.end();
        }
        if (matchLast != 0) {
            sb.append(theText.substring(matchLast));
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
Result: One [a-value] Two [b-value] Three [D] Four
```

Do you have a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What is the logic behind this, why `<sup>D</sup>` only `[D]` not `[D-value}`?

Comment: I would use a `Map<String, Dictionary>` with keys being Dictionary.key -  O(1) search time, instead of `List<Dictionary>` - O(N) search time.

Comment: @Jens - it is just a simplified example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 9, [`Matcher#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.Function-) can accept a callback function to return the replacement for each matched value.

```java
String result = Pattern.compile("<sup>([A-Za-z]+)</sup>").matcher(theText)
    .replaceAll(mr -> "[" + dictionary.stream().filter(f -> f.key().equals(mr.group(1)))
                  .findFirst().map(Dictionary::value)
                  .orElse(mr.group(1)) + "]");
```

Comment: All answers help. Thank you very much! I know that a Map is normally the tool for key value pairs. All answers provide a solution, this answer suits my specific case best.

Comment: @tm1701 You can still use this approach and still create a map from your list. This way you avoid having to stream over the list for every match. If your text has a hundred places that need to be replaced, using this approach you iterate over your list 100 times. With a map you only do it once and only have to look up the value in the map for each match.

Answer (score 2):

Create a map from your list using `key` as key and `value` as value, use the `Matcher#appendReplacement` method to replace matches using the above map and calling `Map.getOrDefault`, use the `group(1)` value as default value. Use String#join to put the replacements in square braces

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Dictionary> dictionary = List.of(
            new Dictionary("a", "a-value", "a-other"),
            new Dictionary("b", "b-value", "b-other"));

    Map<String,String> myMap = dictionary.stream()
                                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Dictionary::key, Dictionary::value));

    String theText  = "One <sup>a</sup> Two <sup>b</sup> Three <sup>D</sup> Four";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<sup>([A-Za-z]+)</sup>").matcher(theText);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, 
                  String.join("", "[", myMap.getOrDefault(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(1)), "]"));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

record Dictionary( String key, String value, String other) {};
```

Answer (score 2):

## Map vs List

As *@Chaosfire* has pointed out in the comment, a `Map` is more suitable collection for the task than a `List`, because it eliminates the need of iterating over collection to access a particular element

```
Map<String, Dictionary> dictByKey = Map.of(
    "a", new Dictionary("a", "a-value", "a-other"),
    "b", new Dictionary("b", "b-value", "b-other")
);
```

And I would also recommend wrapping the `Map` with a class in order to provide continent access to the string-values of the dictionary, otherwise we are forced to check whether a dictionary returned from the map is not `null` and only then make a call to obtain the required value, which is inconvenient. The utility class can facilitate getting the target value in a single method call.

To avoid complicating the answer, I would not implement such a utility class, and for simplicity I'll go with a `Map<String,String>` (which basically would act as a utility class intended to act - providing the value within a single call).

```
public static final Map<String, String> dictByKey = Map.of(
    "a", "a-value",
    "b", "b-value"
);
```

## Pattern.splitAsStream()

We can replace `while`-loop with a stream created via [`splitAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence)) .

In order to distinguish between string-values enclosed with tags `<sup>text</sup>` we can make use of the special constructs which are called *Lookbehind* (`?<=</sup>`) and *Lookahead* (`?=<sup>`).

- `(?<=foo)` - matches a position that immediately precedes the `foo`.
- `(?=foo)` - matches a position that immediately follows after the `foo`;

<sup>For more information, [have a look at this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)</sup>

The *pattern* `"(?=<sup>)|(?<=</sup>)"` would match a position in the given string right before the *opening tag* and immediately after the *closing tag*. So when we apply this *pattern* splitting the string with `splitAsStream()`, it would produce a stream containing elements like `"<sup>a</sup>"` enclosed with *tags*, and plain string like `"One"`, `"Two"`, `"Three"`.

Note that in order to reuse the *pattern* without recompiling, it can be declared on a class level:

```
public static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=<sup>)|(?<=</sup>)");
```

The final solution would result in lean and simple stream:

```
public static void foo(String text) {

    String result = pattern.splitAsStream(text)
        .map(str -> getValue(str))      // or MyClass::getValue
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Instead of tackling conditional logic inside a lambda, it's often better to extract it into a separate method (*sure, you can use a ternary operator and place this logic right inside the* `map` *operation in the stream if you wish instead of having this method, but it'll be a bit messy*):

```
public static String getValue(String str) {
    if (str.matches("<sup>\\p{Alpha}+</sup>")) {
        String key = str.replaceAll("<sup>|</sup>", "");
        return "[" + dictByKey.getOrDefault(key, key) + "]";
    }
    return str;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo("One <sup>a</sup> Two <sup>b</sup> Three <sup>D</sup> Four");
}
```

*Output:*

```
Result: One [a-value] Two [b-value] Three [D] Four
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/v1T)

Comment: Very nice, instructive answer, thank you!